# Is there a better way to have JPanels communicate?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm working on a game which consists entirely of menus/screens which you interact with using buttons, essentially a text-based game but without the typing. To do this I have been working with Swing to create a basic UI, [following this video series.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUEOWVjnIR8)

In order to have actions performed in one panel affect the state of another, I have followed the tutorial and created a UIListener interface, which extends EventListener. When a button is pressed in one JPanel, the fireUIEvent method of the panel is called, which in turn calls the sole method of the interface, uiEventOccurred, which is implemented in an anonymous class inside the main JFrame class. Then the JFrame can do whatever it wants with the event, and modify other JPanels it contains accordingly.

For example, I have a panel that represents the town. It has a button you click to travel to the dungeon. When this button is clicked, the town panel is replaced by the dungeon panel, which has a button you can click to return to the town.

I'll post the relevant classes:

the main frame class

```
public class GameMainFrame extends JFrame{

   public JPanel rightPanel;

   public GameMainFrame(String title) {
      super(title);

      /* Setting The Overall Layout */
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      /* Creating Individual UI Panels */
      UIPanel uip_town = new Town_UI();
      UIPanel uip_dung = new Dungeon_UI();

      /* Creating A Nested Panel */
      rightPanel = new JPanel();
      rightPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      rightPanel.add(uip_text, BorderLayout.WEST);
      rightPanel.add(uip_town, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      /* Creating A Listener To React To Events From The UI Panels */
      uip_town.addUIListener(new UIListener() {
         public void uiEventOccurred(UIEvent event) {
            System.out.println("event text: " + event.getText());
            if (event.getText().equals("goto_dungeon")) {
               rightPanel.remove(uip_town);
               rightPanel.add(uip_dung, BorderLayout.NORTH);
               validate();
            } else if (event.getText().equals("goto_town")) {
               rightPanel.remove(uip_dung);
               rightPanel.add(uip_town, BorderLayout.NORTH);
               validate();
            }
         }
      });

      /* Adding Panels To The Content Pane Of The Frame */
      Container c = getContentPane();
      c.add(uip_info, BorderLayout.WEST);
      c.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }
}
```

UIPanel class

```
public class UIPanel extends JPanel {

   private EventListenerList listenerList;

   public UIPanel() {
      listenerList = new EventListenerList();
   }

   public void fireUIEvent(UIEvent event) {
      Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
      for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i += 2) { 
         if (listeners[i] == UIListener.class) { 
            ((UIListener) listeners[i + 1]).uiEventOccurred(event);
         }
      }
   }

   public void addUIListener(UIListener listener) {
      listenerList.add(UIListener.class, listener);
   }

   public void removeUIListener(UIListener listener) {
      listenerList.remove(UIListener.class, listener);
   }
}
```

Town_UI class

```
public class Town_UI extends UIPanel {

   public Town_UI() {
      Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
      size.height = 466;
      setPreferredSize(size); 

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Town"));   

      JButton btn_dungeon_enter = new JButton("Enter the dungeon");

      add(btn_dungeon_enter);  

      btn_dungeon_enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {      
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fireUIEvent(new UIEvent(this, "goto_dungeon"));
         }
      }); 
   }
}
```

Dungeon_UI class

```
public class Dungeon_UI extends UIPanel {

   public Dungeon_UI() {
      Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
      size.height = 466;
      setPreferredSize(size); 

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Dungeon"));

      JButton btn_town_return = new JButton("Return to town");

      add(btn_town_return);

      btn_town_return.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {            
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fireUIEvent(new UIEvent(this, "goto_town"));
         }        
      });      
   }
}
```

UIEvent object

```
public class UIEvent extends EventObject {

   private String text; 

   public UIEvent(Object source, String text) {
      super(source);
      this.text = text;
   }

   public String getText() { 
      return text;
   }
}
```

UIListener interface

```
public interface UIListener extends EventListener {

   public void uiEventOccurred(UIEvent e);

}
```

I have two problems with this. Number one, it is currently bugged. When I run the application, the Town_UI panel appears with its button "Enter the dungeon", and upon clicking on it the frame correctly updates, replacing the Town_UI panel with the Dungeon_UI panel. However, clicking on the "Return to town" button on the dungeon panel doesn't do anything. When trying to debug this I found that the cause was in the UIPanel method fireUIEvent. When the "Return to town" button is pressed, this method is correctly called, but when it creates the Object array using getListenerList, the array is empty, so it skips the for-loop and no action is performed. Because I am unfamiliar with ActionEvents and EventListeners in Java, though, I am not sure how to fix this.

My other problem is that all of the behaviors that occur when a button is pressed are handled in the anonymous class in the GameMainFrame class. This means that if I want to have a bunch of different buttons all do different things (which I do plan on implementing), I'll need a whole bunch of conditionals in the anonymous class to determine what button is pressed and perform the corresponding behavior. I feel like it would be a lot cleaner if the button behavior could be implemented in the anonymous ActionListener class of each button, but I'm not sure how I should restructure my code so that I can do this but also allow any action on any panel able modify any other panel.

In the tutorial I watched he claimed that this implementation of EventListeners was what you should do in order to avoid making your code a rat's nest, but it seems like that is where my code is heading if I use this implementation for what I am trying to do.

Comment: From the sounds of things, what you really want is some kind of "navigation" controller coupled with a "game model".  The idea been, that you execute a "command" against the controller, which triggers an action/command against the model, which changes the state of the model.  The controller then reacts to this change by updating the UI in some way.  This is (very) broad concept of a MVC. The idea is to try and decouple as much of the decision making process from each area and keep the responsibility contained.

Comment: It looks bad to me.  The more usual way to do it is to separate your game into more distinct bits, a model, a view (the UI) and several controllers.  By putting everything in your GUI, you've basically made the worst error, and you're going to have a terrible time testing and debugging this.  Check out the Wikipedia page on MVC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: One idea might be to break down sections of the code into small MVC concepts, so each screen has it's own model, view and controller, but which is then managed by a higher level model/controller

Comment: I strongly second the recommendations above, especially the last one made by @MadProgrammer. The key is to make software that is easy to debug, easy to test *in isolation*, easy to put together and take apart.

Comment: The overriding concept is - you could end up with just about a single view component, whose content is derived from the model - talk about massively simplified